# Raphael Object Width

Tags: javascript, raphael

Okay I need a little help trying to access the width of a Raphael Object. Here is a link to a fiddle I did.

[TheFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stewbydoo/GbDw9/1371/)

It keeps returning undefined but the object is defined. Kind of confused on why I can't just access it the way I am trying to.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `console.log(circle);` you will see that their is no `width` property on the circle so this is why its `undefined`, Another thing, I don't really thinks you can get a width of a circle, what you can is to get the radius, try using:

```
​console.log(circle.paper.width); // prints the "canvas" width
console.log(circle.attrs.r);     // prints the circle radius, circle.attrs.r * 2 you get
                                 // the width of the circle
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want `circle.getBBox()` which will return the following:

```
x:top left corner x
y:top left corner y
x2:bottom right corner x
y2:bottom right corner y
width:width
height:height
```

It may return an answer which isn't a whole number though.